# Add sub section headers in StickyListHeaders

Tags: android, sticky

I want develop app like this

[image]

I used StickyListHeaders library. I used getHeaderId method. But it doesn't work like I expected.

```
public long getHeaderId(int position) {
    HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<String, String>();
    item = (HashMap<String, String>) getItem(position);
    String headerId = item.get(EMP_ID);
    SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM");
    Date date = null;
    try {
    date = f.parse(item.get(TAG_DATE));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    long milliseconds = date.getTime();
    return Long.parseLong(headerId) + milliseconds;
}
```

Could anyone point me to a good direction which fits my case ?

Answer (score 0):

I now it is too late but still better than nothing...

You must return the same id for items that should be grouped under the same header.

Example:

```
if(position <= 10)
    return 1;
else if(position <= 25 && position > 10)
    return 2;
```

But your getHeaderId() method returns :

```
return Long.parseLong(headerId) + milliseconds;
```

It returns different ids for all views , (because of milliseconds)